# Is there an official torrent for 12.10?

Tags: downloads, 12.10, bittorrent

I like using torrents for many reasons: faster downloads, and I want to be able to give back, reducing load on Canonical's servers.

Is there an official torrent for Ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All downloads, including torrents, can be found [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/).

I've added links to the most downloaded images:

- Desktop: [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent), [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent), [64bit+Mac](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64+mac.iso.torrent).
- Server: [32-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-server-i386.iso.torrent), [64-bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-server-amd64.iso.torrent), [64bit+Mac](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-server-amd64+mac.iso.torrent).

Comment: Thank you -- is there a path to this link that can be found from the main download page (http://www.ubuntu.com/download)?

Comment: @Daniel Note that the URLs are under releases.ubuntu.com, which Ubuntu has full control over due to the way DNS works.

Comment: @Daniel, you can get there, but it's easy to miss: near the bottom of [this page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) there is a link titled `12.10 images and checksums` which points to the linked page.

Answer (score 2):

## Ubuntu 12.10 torrents

- [**ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent**](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)
- [**ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent**](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent)
- [**ubuntu-12.10-server-amd64.iso.torrent**](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-server-amd64.iso.torrent)
- [**ubuntu-12.10-server-i386.iso.torrent**](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-server-i386.iso.torrent)

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised that nobody posted this Ubuntu iso torrent page :)

http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/