# Why is the 12.10 version linking to the 12.04 version?

Tags: versions

Where is the proper download for a bootable disc please? I don't want wubi.

Comment: The link works perfectly and it points to 12.10. Here is the 12.10 link http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=latest

Comment: @devav2 It doesn't always work perfectly for one person, even if it does for another, because sometimes some mirrors are working and some are not. So it's best for these problems to be reported (on Launchpad) whenever even one user is able to produce it (unless it completely goes away on its own). See [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/233358/22949). **ghostwhistler**: If you report this as a bug or find it already reported, please feel free to subscribe [me](https://launchpad.net/~degeneracypressure) if you wish, and I can try to reproduce it.

Comment: Folks: This is not *too localized* because problems with files on Ubuntu mirrors is not a one-time thing; they pop up from time to time (as there are many mirrors, run by widely different people and groups). I can see an argument for closing this as *not a real question*, but we know exactly what it's asking...

Answer (score 2):

### You can get it at the central `releases` server.

If the main [download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) on the Ubuntu website ever has a problem, or when it no longer has Ubuntu 12.10 (once 13.04 comes out), you will always be able to get 12.10 here:

- [`http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/`](http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/)

More generally, if a release's code name is X, its files are available in `http://releases.ubuntu.com/X`.

<sup>End-of-life releases move to `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/X`, but the first URL still works as it's made a redirect. URL's to files inside may not redirect. In any case, folks really shouldn't use EoL releases as security vulnerabilities are not patched when discovered.</sup>

You can access **bootable CD images** there. If you *did* want to use **Wubi** (which I understand you don't), you could get it there too. For that, you'd scroll down to the bottom.

**`.torrent` files for [bittorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bittorrent)** are also there. If you have a reasonably fast Internet connection--DSL or better--then [torrents](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202726/is-there-an-official-torrent-for-12-10) are probably the best and fastest way to get Ubuntu, and it's an easy way to help out by uploading it to others during and after you download it.

You can browse all the supported releases here:

- [`http://releases.ubuntu.com`](http://releases.ubuntu.com)

Clicking a release name there goes into that release's folder as explained above.

### Weird architecture? No problem!

For the minority of users who want ISO images to install on less common, community-supported architectures, those are on a different server:

- [`http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/quantal/release/`](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/quantal/release/)
- [`http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/`](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/)

### Logistics and Troubleshooting

During times of heavy load, downloading from the `releases` server may be slow. Even during normal load, it's generally recommended to download from a mirror--that usually maximizes speed, makes it so you don't have to wait as long for the download to begin, and provides for the efficient distribution of Ubuntu to many people around the world at the same time.

There's nothing wrong with downloading from the `releases` server, especially if you have problems downloading using the download page. One of the things the download page does--besides making it easier for novice users to get the right ISO image--is to select a randomized, probably suitable mirror for you to download from.

Therefore, if there's a problem downloading using the download page, it could be:

- a problem with the download page itself, *or*
- a problem on one or more of the mirrors that get selected.

Either way, the best thing to do (after you've started downloading your file from someplace that's working right, so that's done) is to report the problem by filing a bug on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net) against the [`ubuntu-website-content`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-website-content) package. You can [search for it, and then report it if nobody else has, here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-website-content). If someone else has reported the same problem then you can subscribe to the bug to get notifications and show your interest, and (especially recommended, and totally separate from subscribing) you can use the *This bug affects* link near the top of the bug page to indicate that you are affected.

**Before** reporting a new bug, or if you have any confusion about bugs and bug reporting, it's a very good idea to [read this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs), even though some of the information is not relevant to reporting bugs in `ubuntu-website-content`. [This is also an excellent resource.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: The links don't work as listed. the 12.10 links to 12.04 and gives me the wubi version which, for the third time, i don't want and the disc images will not burn to dvd. this website is a mess

Comment: @ghostwhistler When I go to [the 12.10 link](http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/) I get a page where I can choose what I want to download. On that page, I click [PC (Intel x86) desktop image](http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso). That is an ISO image, it is **the 12.10 version**, and it **can be burned to CD or DVD**. This is working for me and others; if it's not working for you, we need to *figure out* what's going on. As it seems to be working *except* for you, this may be a problem on your end. (1) Try clearing your browser cache. (2) Do you use a proxy/VPN?

Comment: that link is still the wubi file.

Comment: @ghostwhistler Are you able to download ISO images at [this mirror](http://mirror.uoregon.edu/ubuntu-releases//quantal/)? Also, what happens when you [clear your browser cache](http://kb.iu.edu/data/ahic.html)? (Alternatively, try a different web browser?) Do you connect to the Internet through a VPN? Are you accessing the web through a proxy server?

Comment: i downloaded the pc intel x86 desktop image as above. I find it incomprehensible that people misunderstand what I'm asking and that it's not available.

Comment: nothing has worked. it is still the wubi file. how is this not clear?

Comment: @ghostwhistler You said, "i downloaded the pc intel x86 desktop image as above." All I or anyone else can know about what has happened is what you tell us. That sounded a lot like you downloaded something, and that the thing you downloded *was the PC Intel x86 desktop image*. What **did** you mean? Do you mean you clicked the link to *try* to download the PC x86 desktop image from [the mirror](http://mirror.uoregon.edu/ubuntu-releases//quantal/), but got Wubi.exe instead? Assuming that is what happened, you need to tell us: (1) What browser, browser version, and OS are you using?

Comment: (2) Have you cleared your browser's cache and *then* attempted to download the image? (3) Have you tried using a different web browser? If not, *please try a different web browser* also, so we can narrow down them problem. If you have only one browser, you can download another to try. If you cannot do that, please explain why you cannot. (4) Do you connect to the web using a proxy? Do you connect to the Internet via VPN? It's unlikely anyone can help you unless you answer these questions, so please answer them as best you can, and if you cannot answer some of them, please say that.

Comment: different browser makes no difference, nor does how i connect to the internet. the fault lies with the link. the PC Intel x86 IS the wubi file.

Comment: @ghostwhistler It seems to be working fine for everybody but you. Please answer *all 4* of the above questions, including a list of at least two of the browsers and their version numbers that you have been able to reproduce this problem on, and the name and version of the operating system that you are using. We need this information, because the problem you're experiencing is apparently extremely uncommon. You might be *the only person* who is affected. If we are to solve the problem, we need to figure out what's different between your machines and others.

Comment: I have done all of those things and I do not use a proxy. None of this could possibly change the contents of a file. That is still the wubi file. I really don't understand why you cannot just link to the non wubi file i want.

Comment: @ghostwhistler All of those things could potentially introduce problems that change what file you are getting. *We are linking to the correct file*, it is just not working on your system. Do you think we have not double checked? I have double checked every link I or anyone here has provided you--they are *all correct*. If you're not willing to believe this is caused by anything but us giving you wrong links, then there is no way for me or anyone else to help you. If you *are* willing to believe you're experiencing something unusual, *provide all the information I have repeatedly reqested*.

Comment: i have abnswered those questions twice. They have no bearing on this situation. That is now three times. None of those things would never change the file I'm getting. At all.

Comment: Browser and OS name and version? Second browser name and version? VPN? Cache? I have *personally* seen problems like this occur and resolve with changes in *all* the things I've asked about. You can search the web to learn how faulty cached data, proxies (which you did answer), VPN's, browser bugs, and bad browser configuration (usually arising from a bug or customization), can all cause incorrect files, or incorrect versions of files, to be fetched when browsing the web. Or you can ask on a general computing forum (not Ask Ubuntu) about how that works.

Comment: i use firefox and chrome. again, for the fourth time, none of those things are an issue. I empty the cache every time i start these programmes. i'm not in the habit of repeating myself